# How to convert blade to html in Laravel with mix version for assets

Tags: laravel

I used mix in view blade but when I use render for get HTML code, I cannot see the version in assets CSS and JS.

home.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

PHP Code

```
$html = view('home')->render();
```

How can I get html code with version in assets like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css?id=0adb49f1f26bc78ba1d8">
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why would you need this version ? for which use case ?

Comment: For support caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asset like this:

```
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Using asset the version cannot attach after render.